# Same apex method different output

Tags: soql, commandbutton, apex-param, method

I have "Items" object with different statuses. I need to get the following output with single soql query.

Ordered Items: **10** 
Cancelled Items: **3** 
Reviewed Items: **2**

VF Page and apex code below:

```
 Ordered Items: <apex:commandButton value="{!Count}"/>
 Cancelled Items: <apex:commandButton value="{!Count}" />
 Reviewed Items: <apex:commandButton value="{!Count}"/>


Public Integer Count(){
   List<Items__c> items = [SELECT Count(ID) FROM Items__c WHERE Status == 'Ordered' OR Status == 'Cancelled' OR Status == 'Reviewed'];
   return items.size();
}
```

With the above code ofcourse, I get the following output

Ordered Items: **15** 
Cancelled Items: **15** 
Reviewed Items: **15**

Im calling the same method here, but I want to return differently based on the Status.  I tried to use apex:param for the commandButton, but doesn't work.

Any ideas how to implement.  [I want to use only 1 SOQL, with different SOQL and different methods, I can get what I want]

Comment: Does that code actually compile and run? `Items__c` is a custom object so the `Status` field should be custom as well. That means the field should be referenced as `Status__c` not `Status`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though you only have 1 SOQL statement in your code it gets executed 3 times, once for every call to `Count()`.

If you use a map where the key is the status and the value is the count you can do something like the code below. This code will only execute the SOQL once.

```
 Ordered Items: <apex:commandButton value="{!statusCount['Ordered']}"/>
 Cancelled Items: <apex:commandButton value="{!statusCount['Cancelled']}" />
 Reviewed Items: <apex:commandButton value="{!statusCount['Reviewed']}"/>


public Map<String, Integer> statusCount {
    get {
        if (statusCount == null) {
            statusCount = new Map<String, Integer>();
            statusCount.put('Ordered', 0);
            statusCount.put('Cancelled', 0);
            statusCount.put('Reviewed', 0);
            for (Items__c i = [SELECT Status 
                               FROM Items__c
                               WHERE Status in ('Ordered', 'Cancelled', 'Reviewed']) {
                Integer count = statusCount.get(i.Status) + 1;
                statusCount.put(i.Status, count);
            }
        }
        return statusCount;

    }
    set;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the lovely answer.  Want to know, how safe is it to write a SOQL in a get;set; method?

Comment: It is safe because the SOQL will only execute when `statusCount` is null which will only ever happen once